# First insert and then update longitude and latitude in the table

Tags: php, mysql

How can I first insert longitude and latitude then update it when existing? I tried it with the query statement in the code but I am getting this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Table' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\bustracker\index.php on line 28` but if  the insert query is being deleted I am getting the output `Table exist`

```
<?php
$json = '{"latitude":93.86898451,"longitude":40.66561387,"time":"27.04.2015 20:11:05","route":4}';
$data = json_decode ( $json );
$route = "route_" . $data->{'route'};
$latitude = $data->{'latitude'};
$longitude = $data->{'longitude'};
$recordingTime = $data->{'time'};

require 'connection.php';

// check whether route's table exist.
$results = $con->query ( "SHOW TABLES LIKE'" . $route . "'" ) or die ( mysqli_error () );

if (($results->num_rows) == 1) {
  //The error is in this query.
    $con->query ( "INSERT INTO ".$route."(latitude, longitude)
         VALUES(".$latitude.", ".$longitude.")
         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
         latitude = ".$latitude.", 
         longitude = ".$longitude) or die ( $con->error );

echo "Table exist";  
} else {
  $con->query ( "CREATE TABLE " . $route . "
       (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     latitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL, 
     longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,
     created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)" ) or die ( $con->error );

  echo "table was craeted";
}

?>
```

Comment: you have a syntax error `longitude = ".$longitude." ) or die ( $con->error );` remove the `."` after `$longitude`

Comment: Hi @tree. PHP syntax errors can easily be spotted in an IDE - try something like Eclipse, NetBeans or PHP Storm.

Comment: I have removed it but there is another error in this line `longitude = ".$longitude." ) or die ( $con->error )`

Comment: @halfer: I am using eclipse but it shows me many errors in the else statement below but everything is being disappeared if I delete the INSERT statment. Is  there another syntax error in my INSERT query?

Comment: Would you update the question with the most recent copy of the code? Note the syntax error referred to above is a PHP error, not a SQL error.

Comment: @halfer: As I said all errors are disappeared  when I delete the INSERT statement I have updated the question code I just deleted the point after `$longitude`.

Comment: @tree: there's still a spurious double quote character `"`. You removed the dot, but left the double quote. (Augwa's original comment indicated that there were *two* characters that needed to removed.) This is a PHP syntax error, not a SQL error. Your code appears vulnerable to **SQL Injection**. Best practice is **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**. Otherwise, potentially unsafe strings need to be properly **escaped** before including them in SQL text.  Expressions in the **`ON UPDATE`** can reference values from the values list e.g. **`latitude = VALUES(latitude)`**.

Comment: ... also, in the SQL statement, there's three columns listed in the column list, and only two expressions in the VALUES list. It's not at all clear what unique constraint exists on the table, and how that statement is going to throw cause a duplicate key exception.

Comment: Ok thanks for your Explanation I will take it into consideration. I removed the the double quote and I am getting now the following `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` what is wrong with the statement?

Comment: Ok I removed the created_at column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to use a **prepared statement** with **bind placeholders**.  For debugging dynamically generated SQL, it often helps to assign the generated SQL text to a variable, and then it's available, for display for debugging.

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `".$route."`(latitude, longitude, created_at)
          VALUES( ? , ? , NOW() )
          ON DUPLICATE KEY 
          UPDATE latitude = VALUES(latitude)
               , longitude = VALUES(longitude)";

  #var_dump($sql); # for debugging
  $stmt = $con->prepare($sql) or die ( $con->error );
  $stmt->bind_param("ss",$latitude,$longitude);
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->close();
```

In this example, we need to be sure that `$route` is a valid identifier; there's potential here for SQL injection via the value of `$route`. (We can't supply a bind placeholder for an identifier.)

It's not at all clear how the insert is going to throw a "duplicate key" exception; we don't see which sets of columns are defined as the PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEYs.

We can reference the values from the VALUES list of the INSERT in expressions in the ON UPDATE by using the special VALUES() function, as demonstrated above. We don't have to supply multiple copies of the "latitude" value in the statement.

Comment: It works fine thaks. Just one question can I make my `latitude` column as UNIQUE KEY in my case?